# Routing via MatAutocomplette Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement the autocomplete component of Angular Material:

It works fine, it at least displays and I see the data from my json. Is there a way to route on click of the event, that is when something is selected from the autocomplete to a page?

My HTML currently looks like this:

```
    <div class="example-form">
  <div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="schoolForm">
      <mat-form-field class="example-form">
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Gib den Namen deiner Schule ein" formControlName="schoolGroup" required
          [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
        <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of schoolGroupOptions | async" [label]="group.letter">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let name of group.names" [value]="name">
              {{name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    <form [formGroup]="schoolForm">
      <mat-form-field class="example-form1">
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Gib den Nachnamen deines Lehrers ein">
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/teachers">Ergebnisse anzeigen</button>
</div>
```

how should the TS. look like?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete) we see that `MatAutoComplete` exposes an event when an option is selected.

`@Output() optionSelected`

Reading further, we need to add `[matAutocomplete]` as a directive onto our text input, and pass it a reference to the auto-complete in our template.

To do this, I create a `mat-autocomplete` and give it the template literal name of `#navigable` which we pass into the `[matAutocomplete]` directive.

**This gives us the following html template**

```html
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="navigable">
        <mat-autocomplete #navigable (optionSelected)="chooseOption($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.route">{{group.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

*Note* we can bind to `(optionSelected)` on the `mat-autocomplete` as it is the event stated in the API to be called when the value is selected for our attached input.

**in our .ts file**

```
@Component()
export class MyExampleComponent {

 // group dummy object, hard-coded for demonstration purposes
 // I've chosen to store the route directly on the group. 
 // You should choose whichever strategy suits your needs
 groups = [
    {
      name: "One",
      route: 'one'
    },
    {
      name: "Two",
      route: 'two'
    },
    {
      name: "Three",
      route: 'three'
    }
  ];
  
  // inject router for navigation
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  chooseOption(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    // destructure the value and navigate.
    const {option: {value}} = event
    this.router.navigate([value]);
  }

}
```

and that is it. We will now navigate as soon as an option is selected in the dropdown list.